# Nuxt 2 SSr app do not run on Cpanel properly

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js, cpanel

I use firebase (firestore) in this app. In order to deploy my app to Cpanel, I just create dist folder using npm run generate command and put this folder into the Cpanel. Everything works fine, but when I create or delete a doc, these changes does not appear in the app.

Everything works well on localhost. I deployed the same project to the heroku. Everything works well in Heroku app as well. What I do wrong? I run npm run build, but this command does not create dist folder.